# How to html escape variables in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I would like to display several variables in a web page using Thymeleaf.

I have the code set as follows...

```
<span th:text="${foo.bar}" />
```

The problem is that when property foo.bar contains multiple spaces in a row, they are displayed as one (expected behaviour for HTML).

```
e.g. "hello        world" => "hello world"
```

Is there a "Thymeleaf" way to HTML escape the value of the variable so that the value visually appears exactly as it should be?

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way is to use HTML's way of accomplishing this: either using `<pre>` tags (`<pre th:text="${foo.bar}" />`), or else using the css `white-space` property and changing the style of your `<span>` tags that contain variables.

I guess you could also replace ' ' with `&nbsp;` (like this: `<span th:text="${#strings.replace(foo.bar, ' ', '&nbsp;')}" />`, but that would be my last option.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved this by adding the following to my css file:

.span {
  white-space: pre;
}